# Viewport and debug session

Tags: directx11, viewport

I define and set viewport using this piece of code:

```
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;

viewport.Width = (FLOAT)pBspWindow->GetWidth();
viewport.Height = (FLOAT)pBspWindow->GetHeight();
viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;

pD3DContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
```

If I remove MaxDepth/MinDepth members and run my application under debug session triangle will not be shown.

This behaviour doesn't appear under release session.

I searched on MSDN, but couldn't find anything.

I'm interested why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rely on uninitialized state. `D3D11_VIEWPORT` is a POD type, without any constructors or so. In this case, you can get different result each time your app runs.

In Debug mode, compilers initialize variables in different manner - they use [Magic Debug Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values), add guard bytes and much more to check for validity of your code. For instance, if you check values of your uninitialized viewport under debug session, you will probably see -107374176, which is `~0x06666660 + 1`. Probably it is a value chosen by MS to flag uninitialized floating point numbers.

In release version, none of this happens - all additional checks are disabled. So you probably hit a values, that are valid for D3D. Coincidence.

Basically, [you can classify that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c) (using variables, that were not initialized) as undefined behaviour.

Comment: It make sense if you want to debug your code regardless of whether it is a D3Dx app or a classic stuff. I had to ask because I scratched my head for a while looking for a solution :). thnx

Comment: Note that if you use ``CD3D11_VIEWPORT``, the C++ wrapper for ``D3D11_VIEWPORT``, then it has a constructor and does initialize the struct.